# How to insert a document in OrientDb?

Tags: orientdb

Although there is a similar question with an answer I am still unable to insert a row that contains a document.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

I have the below setup on OrientDB version 2.2.x.

```
CREATE CLASS TranslatableText ABSTRACT;
CREATE PROPERTY TranslatableText.de IF NOT EXISTS STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY TranslatableText.en IF NOT EXISTS STRING;

CREATE CLASS Product;
CREATE PROPERTY Product.id IF NOT EXISTS INTEGER;
CREATE PROPERTY Product.name IF NOT EXIST EMBEDDEDMAP TranslatableText;
```

Then; I want to run the following INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO Product (id, name) VALUES (1, {"@type":"d", "@class": "TranslatableText", "de":"Auto", "en":"Car"});
```

And I get an error similar to the one below:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'Car.name' has been declared as EMBEDDEDMAP but an incompatible type is used. Value: TranslatableText{en:Car} DB name="some_db"
```

**Note**: Please ignore small typos that you may see in the syntax as I typed all from scratch. Assume that there are no syntax errors, I've checked for all of these with some co-workers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SET with EMBEDDEDMAP, example:

```
insert into Product SET id=1,name={"de":"Auto","en":"Car"}
```

Comment: still getting the same error. I also tried without non-abstract definition

Answer (score 1):

OK. I figured that there is misunderstanding on our side. EMBEDDEDMAP is complex data type which is providing scheme-less key-value (json-like) storage.

Assigning a "Class" validation to EMBEDDEDMAP actually violates / abuses the real usage of EMBEDDEDMAP. Therefore we get the error above.

If one needs to store a specific document with a specific scheme EMBEDDED is the way to go.

Basically;

```
CREATE CLASS TranslatableText ABSTRACT;
CREATE PROPERTY TranslatableText.de IF NOT EXISTS STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY TranslatableText.en IF NOT EXISTS STRING;

CREATE CLASS Product;
CREATE PROPERTY Product.id IF NOT EXISTS INTEGER;
CREATE PROPERTY Product.name IF NOT EXIST EMBEDDED TranslatableText;
```

is the correct setup. After that one can use any documented notation.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to re-phrase the Question, since the document itself wasn't the issue?